# RadComboBox, how to get selectedItem

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, radcombobox

```
            Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

        sb.Append("<script language=javascript>")

        sb.Append("     function SetValueInBody() {")
        sb.Append("         var _dllGetDynamicFieldKey = $find('" + _dllGetDynamicFieldKey.ClientID + "');")
        sb.Append("         alert('Set Value: ' + _dllGetDynamicFieldKey.SelectedItem);")
        sb.Append("     }")

        sb.Append("</script>")
```

I'm trying to get the selected item from a radComboBox in Jquery with the intention of populating a RadEditor against it. I'm generating teh JS in the back end as above where dllGetDynamicFieldKey is the RadComboBox, the above method is how I've seen it done to get the selected value however it always comes back undefined for me when the alert is fired. Any ideas whats correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apologies, got it, I should have used .get_value() to get the selection